# Utilizing subset data frames in poLAC models

Tags: r

I am am using a national data set with weights, strata, and psu. I utilized the codes from the survey data guidelines to create variance estimation. I then created a data frame for the subset in which I am interested in examining. Now I am trying to figure out how to use this data frame in my LCA model. I tried a few different things and I am absolutely stuck. How do I apply this data frame to my LCA model?

BTW, my LCA runs perfectly fine without the subset but I must incorporate the subset to account for the variance.

```
#Variance Estimation
nh2 <- svydesign(id=~PSU_P, strata=~STRAT_P,
             nest = TRUE,
             weights=~WTFA_SA,
             data= nh)

# subset 
subgrp <- subset(nh2, Black < 2 & SEX > 1)

#LCA codes 
f5<-  cbind( hit_use, hivtest, worrhccost, talkgp, lastvisit=lastvisit +  1) ~ age18_24 + age25_35 + age36_45 + age46_55 +  inc0_34 + inc35_49 + inc50_74 + inc75_99 + inc0_49 + inc50_99

lc3<-poLCA(f5, nh, nclass=3, na.rm = FALSE, nrep=10, maxiter=3000)
```